# Is that possible to trigger a jquery plugin function from a vuejs method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers, vue.js

Assuming that there are some conditions on the vuejs side that I keep as data. So if the condition changes, then I want to trigger the corresponding function or initialise a plugin on jquery side.

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#tracking',
    data: {
        condition:'condition1'
        //condition:'condition2'
    }
});


jQuery('#tracking-picker-condition1').periodpicker({

});

jQuery('#tracking-picker-condition2').periodpicker({

});
```

Comment: The code example is not working. Include Vue in it. Also, why do you want to use Vue with jQuery?

Comment: Hi @motanelu it's just a simulation, not working copy. 
Because i want to use that "period picker" plugin. If there is a vue version of period picker plugin then it fits too. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is totally possible :)
Although custom components are the preferred choice https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-datepicker , you can call jQuery stuff anywhere you want. 
You can even find in the official vue 2.0 docs such an example for the select2 jquery plugin.
https://jsfiddle.net/yyx990803/fruqrvdL/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=fruqrvdL

It is used as `$(this.$el)` where `this.$el` is the component identifier, but you can use any id of your choise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Cristi Jora

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is [watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. @Rashad Saleh